# How do shared hosting servers keep executing code from crossing accounts?

Tags: linux, security, permissions

I am kind of curious, how does a hosting server support multiple users with php but keep each user away from the other code?
The 'easy' solution i thought were file permissions. So every user can have www-data belong to their group and the server would have executing access but the users cant access the others file.

But then i realize the user running the php would be www-data who has permission to read everyones data. So how does a shared host prevent this from happening?

PS: I personally use nginx (with fastcgi php). But i am somewhat familiar on how apache works.

Answer (score 0):

most of them use apache module mod_userdir : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a basedir configuration that will limit each virtualhost to a sub-folder.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781185/php-a-different-open-basedir-per-each-virtual-host